# can't create files in typo3 inside fileadmin

Tags: fopen, extbase, typo3-4.5

I am building an extension with extbase where I need to create a pdf file inside fileadmin folder with php from a controller :

```
fopen("/fileadmin/pdf/anass.pdf", "w") or die('could not create file');
```

The permission is granted to write files ... so I think I made a mistake writing the path. Could somebody please help me?

PS: I am working on typo3 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you're specifying absolute path in the filesystem and most probably there's no such path like `/fileadmin/pdf/...` there.

Quite safe would be using some **[TYPO3 constant](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/GlobalValues/Constants/Index.html)** to specify where's your app's root i.e. `PATH_site`, like:

```
  fopen(PATH_site . "/fileadmin/pdf/anass.pdf", "w") or die('could not create file');
```

it will use the path like (sample)

```
/var/www/your-app/fileadmin/pdf/anass.pdf
```

note, that if you should use slash before `fileadmin` or not is OS/server config depended, so just check if your `PATH_site` ends with slash or not.